# I want to save my pdf file in one folder with my 2 upload form the web and the mobile

Tags: php

I want to upload my file in one folder but it seems like its not working at all  yet i create a resume folder in REVISE/MOBILE/uploads/resume/ here are my 2 thesame upload form codes with the web is located in htdocs/REVISE.php while the mobile 1 upload form is located in htdocs/REVISE/MOBILE/upload.php

```
$uploadOk = true;

$folder_dir = "Revise/Mobile/uploads/resume/";


$base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 

$resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 


$file = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php is the common approach

Comment: can you post upload code and form code

Comment: its a registration that require a resume pdf file..